# Bound the equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, functional-inequalities

Can anyone help me to bound the following equation?

Here, we have $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k = n$

$w = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(c^{i-1}\left(x_i^2+2 x_i\sum_{j=i+1}^k x_j\right)\right)$

What I want to bound is $r = \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{w}}+\sqrt{\frac{cx_2^2}{w}}+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{c^kx_k^2}{w}}$

For example, if $k = 3$ then $w = x_1^2+2x_1x_2+2x_1x_3+cx_2^2+2cx_2x_3+c^2x_3^2$.

$$r = \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{w}}+\sqrt{\frac{cx_2^2}{w}} + \sqrt{\frac{c^2x_3^2}{w}}$$

I have tried Cauchy-Schwarz inequality one the above and I can derive the following result 
\begin{align*}
r^2 \leq \frac{3(x_1^2+cx_2^2+c^2x_3^2)}{w} \Rightarrow r\leq \sqrt{\frac{3(x_1^2+cx_2^2+c^2x_3^2)}{w}}
\end{align*}
However if the number of variables is $k=m$ the ratio will be approxed $\sqrt{m}$. 
Is it possible to give a constant upper bound for $r$ in the general case?

Comment: I do not understand how $w$ is defined precisely. Can you make the dots explicit? What is the coefficient of $x_ix_j$?

Comment: For $x_1x_j$ all of the coefficient is 2 and for $x_2x_j$ all of the coefficient times c where c is a constant. Generally,  the coefficient of $x_ix_j = 2\cdot c^{i-1}, \forall j > i$

Comment: Is this what you mean: $w = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(c^{i-1}\left(x_i^2+2 x_i\sum_{j=i+1}^n x_j\right)\right)$

Comment: @marty cohen Yes! But the second summation should be revised from $j = i+1$ to $k$

Comment: It seems unlikely that a constant upper bound exists. Also, how is $r$ defined if $\omega$ or $c$ is negative? If $c\geq1$ then $\omega$ is always positive, but for $c<1$ it is not.